# custom flash components for android

Tags: flash, components

Am developing a software to make database for patients records in dental clinic using adobe air it worked fine on desktop but when I tried to make it for android the component look very tiny you can't use them I tried to change the size of them but didn't succeed especially the list component so I need large size component to use with android I tired the feathers but was not successful they were too complicated I need simple ones with drag and drop like the original flash components where can I find something like that?

Am using flash professional cc

Comment: you know ".", "," or "?"......

Comment: @ZerO programmers know ; && !